# AngularJS - concatenating dynamic content on AngularStrap $alert (?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

hello guys I have an Angular Strap alert where I want to put some dynamic content.

Look, this is the html I have so far:

```
<div ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems">
  <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="lineLeague in lineItem">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">{{:: lineLeague[0].leagueName}}</h3>
    </div>
```

as you can see there is a class named `panel-title` which is the same parameter that I want to show on my alert, I thought that only placing `{{:: lineLeague[0].leagueName}}` was enough, but once the alert shows up, the result is **Sorry, no lines for {{:: lineLeague[0].leagueName}} at this moment :(** and this is my code:

```
var noLinesAlert = $alert({
  title: 'Sorry, no lines for {{:: lineLeague[0].leagueName}} at this moment :(',
  container: '.no-lines-alert',
  type: 'danger',
  dismissable: false,
  show: false
})
```

so what are your suggestions ?

Comment: I assume that you call the $alert service in a controller. You can just use the $scope to access lineLeague[0].

Comment: @HimmetAvsar I just tried, I also did the question on the Angular Strap Git, and here is the answer: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1403 but actually I do not know how to do it.